# how do i get the about method to read the variables?

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance

Im trying to get the new student I made to read the about method, however the variables in the about method say they are not assigned. I thought they were because I had set them as defaults in each class that I made.

```
namespace studentHeirarchy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            runStudent();   
        }
        static void runStudent()
        {
            Student one = new Student();
            Console.WriteLine(one.About());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

namespace studentHeirarchy
{
    public class ColumbiaStudent : Student
    {
        public bool isInOOP;

        public ColumbiaStudent()
        {
            isInOOP = true;
        }

        public String About()
        {
            string About = "my favorite course is OOP";
            return About;
        }

        public void GetOOPString()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

namespace studentHeirarchy
{
    public class Student : Person
    {
        public int NumCourses;
        public string SchoolName;

        public Student()
        {
            NumCourses = 1;
            SchoolName = "Columbia";
        }

        public string About()
        {
            string About = string.Format("my name is{0}, I am {1} years old, I attend {2} and am taking {3} courses."),  Name, Age, SchoolName, NumCourses;
            return About;
        }

        public void AddCourse()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DropCourse()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

namespace studentHeirarchy
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Age;
        public string Name;

        public Person()
        {
            Age = 17;
            Name = "Jeff";
        }

        public string About()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with your `string.Format`. You're closing the parentheses, then it thinks you're declaring other variables:

```
string About = string.Format("my name is{0}, I am {1} years old, I attend {2} and am taking {3} courses."),  Name, Age, SchoolName, NumCourses;
```

should be:

```
string About = string.Format("my name is{0}, I am {1} years old, I attend {2} and am taking {3} courses.",  Name, Age, SchoolName, NumCourses);
```

Fixing this will yield the output:

> my name isJeff, I am 17 years old, I attend Columbia and am taking 1 courses.

Additionally, I would urge you to look at C# [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx). that is the core of another problem and where everybody else's answers are getting sidetracked by. Specifically you need to understand `virtual`, `override`, and `new` (`new` as it relates to method signatures, not instantiation).

Comment: thank you very much, do you know if there is a video on polymorphism? i feel i understand better when i see it bein done

Comment: Ha, that was a nasty typo :)

Answer (score 0):

you need declare your method virtual, in .net , it is not virtual by default. Basically , you are hiding the method.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the base constructors of parent classes. There is a problem with the `About` method as well which has to be virtual, otherwise the wrong `About` might be called.

Below is the corrected code:

```
namespace studentHeirarchy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            runStudent();   
        }
        static void runStudent()
        {
            Student one = new Student();
            Console.WriteLine(one.About());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

namespace studentHeirarchy
{
    public class ColumbiaStudent : Student
    {
        public bool isInOOP;

        public ColumbiaStudent() : base()
        {
            isInOOP = true;
        }

        public override String About()
        {
            string About = "my favorite course is OOP";
            return About;
        }

        public void GetOOPString()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

namespace studentHeirarchy
{
    public class Student : Person
    {
        public int NumCourses;
        public string SchoolName;

        public Student() : base()
        {
            NumCourses = 1;
            SchoolName = "Columbia";
        }

        public override string About()
        {
            string About = string.Format("my name is{0}, I am {1} years old, I attend {2} and am taking {3} courses."),  Name, Age, SchoolName, NumCourses;
            return About;
        }

        public void AddCourse()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DropCourse()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

namespace studentHeirarchy
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Age;
        public string Name;

        public Person()
        {
            Age = 17;
            Name = "Jeff";
        }

        public virtual string About()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after doing so, the Name, Age, NumCourses, and SchoolName variables are still unused in my about method